# Make Path share button to website

Tags: html, path, share

Anyone knows how to add https://path.com/ Share button to web?

Can I use this code?

`<a href="path://text?Text to share">Share to path</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need share something to **path**, you must use their API's. https://path.com/developers